# Problems with poject's opening

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I have a problem with opening project on the other PC. It literally can't open in VStudio. I get errors like: "One or more projects from the solution were not loaded", or "Can not find the specified file". But there is no problem on my PC. So could you help me to make my project work on any PC ( Visual Studio 2015+) if it's possible. Here is a link to full project, try to launch it on your VS.
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PT8gHTvze88DI4DCahRrQfbiY6qeoopV

I tried to do something in properties, but it didn't help me.

Comment: "2015+" doesn't help much.  If you use VS2017 or VS2019 then you need to go back to the installer and add C++/CLI support.  They don't install it by default.

Comment: This features are already installed. So there is a big question why it doesn't work. Also i finnaly runned it on the other PC with vs2019, but i should be able to run it in the university to show my game, so.. I don't know how to make it work.